# trying to install a script with composer

Tags: composer-php, installation

Trying install a script using composer but i'm unable to install it. installation documentation says upload the content to your server and run these commands.

script uploaded to /home/example/public_html

1.You will need to install the composer dependencies in your application by running the following command inside the root directory of your app. "composer install"

I tried running the command "composer install" and i got a error

```
root@vserv:/# composer install
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Comment: What script you're talking about?

Comment: it's a 3rd party script purchased from codecanyon. Software Framework: Laravel

Comment: Then the message should be quite clear. You should have `composer.json` inside of this script - you need to run `composer install` from directory with this file. If you uploaded project to `/home/example/public_html` then you may try `cd /home/example/public_html && composer install`.

Comment: i did try the same command with out `&&`  now with `&&`  it worked.

Comment: now i have another issue. `Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/annotations[v1.6.0].
    - doctrine/annotations v1.6.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
` i believe i need to upgrade my php version from 7.0 to 7.1 or 7.2 is that correct?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: work away around i edited the `composer.lock` and installation continued

Comment: Everything works perfectly now. thank you all  for the support.